# How to get ajax response from cross-domain by posting some data to the controller method.while working at online server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, cross-domain

I want to get array data from Codeigniter controller,With ajax request.I am posting some data to the controller for getting related data from database.It works fine locally but when I uploaded my website to online domain and hosting I cant get any response.

My code works fine on local server.But when I Uploaded it to online server my ajax requests not work at all.There is no available response data.below is code works fine at local server

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url()?>getstate',
            data:'country_id='+country_id,
            success:function(data){
              var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               $(dataObj).each(function(){

                          // Add options
                          $.each(dataObj,function(index,data){
                              alert(data['data_name']);

                          });


                    });
                }
 })
```

server side code is

```
 public function getstate()
    {
        $state = array();
        $country_id = $this->input->post('country_id');
        $state = $this->Country_model->getstate($country_id);
        echo json_encode($state);

    }
```

I have try this

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.oppen("GET","http://www.my-domain-name.co/getstate",true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
          if((xhr.readyState == 4)&&(xhr.status==200))
          {
              var ob=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
              alert(ob.name);
              }
        };
        xhr.send();
```

but does not work

How  can I do this.I am new to this situation...

Comment: do you get any message (404,500 etc)

Comment: yes: 303 See Other

Answer (score 0):

their are **4** possible reason/solution

**first** please check your CI version if it is old one please check for base_url definition

if site got secure url(https) now .

**2nd** 
 add crossDomain parameter to jquery ajax function 
as follow :

```
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
         crossDomain : true,
        url:'<?php echo base_url()?>getstate',
        data:'country_id='+country_id,
        success:function(data){
          var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           $(dataObj).each(function(){

                      // Add options
                      $.each(dataObj,function(index,data){
                          alert(data['data_name']);

                      });


                });
            }
})
```

**[check this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** for more details

**3rd**
its got blocked by the server your are requesting to then it wont be possible until you have the target web site under your control or other access specifires

**4th**
blocked by your hosting : set headers (
like

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin ,
- Content-Security-Policy
- etc

)for allowing them .